# Angular grunt build (from yeoman) breaks my app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

after running the build from the `/dist` folder I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=ourname&p1=Error%3A…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A462)
```

nothing I do seems to solve this problem

this is the grunt task flow - adapted 1 to 1 from yeoman angular-generator:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        //pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        coveralls:{
        options:{
          coverage_dir:'coverage'
        }
         },
        jshint:{
            files:['app/js/**/*.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
            options:grunt.file.readJSON('.jshintrc')


        },
        watch:{
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['copy:css', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/css/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/js/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: ['last 1 version'],
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
//            server: '.tmp'
        },
            rev: {
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        src: [
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/{,*/}*.js',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/fonts/*'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            useminPrepare: {
                html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
                options: {
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    html: {
                        steps: {'js': ['concat','ngmin']},
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            },
            usemin: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
                css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
                options: {
                    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
                }
            },
            imagemin: {
                dist: {
                    files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
                    }]
                }
            },
            svgmin: {
                dist: {
                    files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
                        src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
                    }]
                }
            },
            cssmin: {
                // By default, your `index.html` <!-- Usemin Block --> will take care of
                // minification. This option is pre-configured if you do not wish to use
                // Usemin blocks.
                // dist: {
                //   files: {
                //     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                //       '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                //       '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                //     ]
                //   }
                // }
            },
            htmlmin: {
                dist: {
                    options: {
                        /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                         // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                         //collapseWhituseminPrepareespace: true,
                         collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                         removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                         removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                         useShortDoctype: true,
                         removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                         removeOptionalTags: true*/
                    },
                    files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        src: ['*.html', 'partials/*.html'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                    }]
                }
            },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        'lib/**/*',
                        'img/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
                        'fonts/*',
                        'languages/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/img',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img',
                    src: [
                        'generated/*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css',
                dest: '.tmp/css/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },
//        cdnify: {
//            dist: {
//                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
//            }
//        },
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/js',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/js'
                }]
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                options:{
                    compress:false,
                    mangle:false
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/scripts.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/js/scripts.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },


//        concat:{
//            options:{
//                seperator:';'
//            },
//            dist:{
//                src :['app/js/**/*.js', 'app/lib/**/*.js'],
//                dest :'dist/app/js/<%pkg.name%>.js'
//
//            }
//        },
        exec:{
            instrument:{
                cmd: function(){
                    return 'istanbul instrument app/js -o app/instrumentjs';
                }

            },
            djangoUp:{
              cmd: function(){
                  var command = 'workon stokeet-api  && cd ../stokeet-api/ && python manage.py runserver> /dev/null 2>&1 && cd ../angular/ & ';
                  return command;
              }
            },

            webserverUp:{
              cmd: function(){
                  var command = 'cd ../angular/ && node ./scripts/web-server.js > /dev/null 2>&1 &';
                  return command;
              }

            }
        },
        karma:{
            unit:{
                configFile:'config/karma.conf.js',
                autoWatch:true,
                browsers:['PhantomJS']
            },
            ci:{
                configFile:'config/karma.conf.js',
                singleRun:true,
                autoWatch:false,
                browsers:['Firefox','PhantomJS']
            },
            buildTest:{
                configFile:'config/karma.conf.js',
                singleRun:true,
                autoWatch:false,
                browsers:['PhantomJS']
            }

        }



    });
    grunt.registerTask('coverage',['coveralls']);
    grunt.registerTask('default',['jshint']);
    grunt.registerTask('instrument',['exec: instrument']);
//    grunt.registerTask('concat',['concat']);
    grunt.registerTask('dev_up',['exec:djangoUp', 'exec:webserverUp']);
    grunt.registerTask('test',[
                            'clean:server',
                            'concurrent:test',
                            'autoprefixer',
                            'connect:test',
                            'karma:buildTest']),
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
                            'clean:dist',
                            'useminPrepare',
                            'concurrent:dist',
                            'autoprefixer',
                            'concat',

                            'copy:dist',
                            'ngmin',
                            'cssmin',
                            'uglify',
                            'rev',
                            'usemin'
    ]);
    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

};
```

You can see I tried overriding the `usemin` default flow, but that didn't help

I suspect this has to do with the known angular minification problem, but since ngmin is running here, and all my code (Not sure about the plugins) does respect the angular minification safe array notation I'm not sure .

any ideas? I'll be glad for any help with this

Answer (score 2):

I will try to be brief explaining the problem when building with usemin 2.0.x and ngmin in Angularjs (according my experience, I may be wrong in something, if yes please correct me):

The normal flow in the Build grunt task is that ngmin is executed before usemin and others, to let the code with injections like this:

```
...
angular.module("Config",[])
    .config(["$httpProvider","CONSTANTS","ERRORS","HEADERS",function(a,b,c,d){var
...
```

usemin 0.1.x was using only 'concat', but the version 2.0.x is using 'concat' and 'uglifyjs' so, after concatenate the code, it changes the javascript code again, this corrupts the ngmin, as you can see in the following example:

```
...
angular.module("Config",[])
    .config(function(a,b,c,d){var
...
```

So you have to stop it defining the flow in useminPrepare, like the following:

```
useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                steps: {'js': ['concat']},
                post: {}
            }
        }
    },
```

**Edit**
You can add the task in the grunt tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [ 
    'clean:dist', 
    'jshint', 
    'useminPrepare', 
    'imagemin', 
    'cssmin', 
    'ngmin', 
    'uglify', 
    'rev', 
    'usemin'
])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: so basically you suggesting to disable the use uglify.js in the build? I can (and already) do that while retaining some benefits of uglify.js with disabling mangling while allowing compressing. but I'm sure there is a way around this, this is the whole point of ng-min, of angular string array notation. etc..

Comment: no, I am using uglify, but in another step before usemin, you can have in your Gruntfile's tasks:
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jshint',
    'useminPrepare',
    'imagemin',
    'cssmin',
    'ngmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

Comment: can you add your uglify task setup to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue after `yo angular` setup without any modifications.

The following discussion helped me resolve it:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/164

**In a nutshell:**

Search for

`<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->`

and change it to

`<!-- build:js(app/..) scripts/vendor.js -->`

Comment: if you have your .js files in app you should not change this! Only if you have them outside app folder

Answer (score 1):

I think the default GruntFile.js has changed a bit in Yeoman since this question was answered.

This worked for me:

Uncommented out the following `uglify` block and added the `mangle:false` option.

```
uglify: {
   options:{mangle:false},
   dist: {
     files: {
       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
       ]
     }
   }
},
```

Then I commented out the `ngmin` line (which took forever to run anyway).

The result is non-mangled js which is considerably larger, but runs my angular code well. Eventually I suppose ngmin will be smart enough to handle things more seamlessly, but until then I'm okay with the extra bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Is everything working if you only serve the files (grunt server)?
So: No problem with angular this way?

Have your read the linked error page?
http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector:modulerr?p0=ourname&p1=Error:%E2%80%A6(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8085%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:32:462)

It tells you, that there is a problem with our "ourname" module.

Do you have some code for us?

I am not quite sure, what this changes, but you can also define it like:

```
useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    steps: {'js': ['concat','ngmin']},
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        },
```

https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#flow 
Did you missed the "flow"?

Maybe one of the questions helps to find the solution ;)

Comment: I did mix flow and html.. but that wasn't the problem (not even sure it's not a debug remnant). also ngmin won't work as a step here (at least currently). and even Ngmin doesn't correctly protect the app from being broken by uglifyjs.  currently I rebuilt the build process without minification (which wasn't easy) and the app works. lets say that usemin docs are almost useless and yeoman build in code comments are misleading. I'll try to contribute a doc fix later.

Answer (score -3):

if you are using Yeoman for building your angular application.

Simply type

```
yo doctor
```

This will help you to identify what all issues are present with your application.

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✖ Node.js version

Your Node.js version is outdated.
Upgrade to the latest version: https://nodejs.org

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
```