# Yeoman AngularJS Grunt breaks modules

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm working on an AngularJS application using Yeoman with Grunt. When using the `grunt serve` command there's no problem at all. However, when I use the `grunt` command and take a look at the website, I get these errors:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module webshopAdminApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.slider due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.slider' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My grunt file:

```
// Generated on 2014-10-02 using generator-angular 0.9.3
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9090,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'lumino.gidomanders.nl',
        livereload: 35730
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']), //Matches everything that does not contain a '.' (period)
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9091,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/../'
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }],
        options: {
            cache: false
        }
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html', 'views/{,*/*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'views/{,*/*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/{,*/}*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

My karma.config.js has this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js',
      'bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cached-resource/angular-cached-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-slider/src/slider.js',
      'bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js',
      'bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js',
      'bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
app/
    scripts/
        app.js
    styles/
    views/
bower_components/
dist/
node_modules/
test/
bower.json
Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

In my app.js you find this:

```
angular
        .module('webshopAdminApp', [
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngResource',
            'ngRoute',
            'ngSanitize',
            'ngTouch',
            'ui.router',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'ngCachedResource',
            'ui.slider',
            'LocalStorageModule',
            'bootstrapLightbox',
            'angularFileUpload',
            'ngTagsInput',
            'ui.tinymce'
        ])
```

I'm sure all of the modules I use are loaded. I checked the vendor.{hash}.js file and all the modules are in there. When I remove the ui.slider module completely, I get the same error with a different module, so it's not the module or the implementation of it.

I've searched on the internet and only found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098680/angular-grunt-build-from-yeoman-breaks-my-app), where the problem is with uglify converting injections. I've tried all the given solutions, but none worked. I don't want to disable uglify. I don't know what the problem is, I've built another AngularJS application with exactly the same specs and configuration without any problems.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The main difference between `serve` and straight `grunt` are the tests. Where are your error messages appearing, as there may be a config problem in your test modules

Comment: There's also a difference where `grunt serve` does not create a vendor file with all modules, it creates a reference to the actual files in the bower_components directory. So when using `grunt serve` there's no problem because the modules are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've determined that all module dependency configuration is correct or appears to be.

To more clearly determine which modules are failing, a process of elimination is needed.

If you find that there are errors popping up from modulerr for a missing module or provider, then slowly remove module dependencies one by one and rebuild in order to find out which dependency is throwing the error.

Then, remove the dependency and find another one that could possibly satisfy it.

If your issue is with LocalStorageModule, I recommend going with ngStorage and seeing if that solves your problems, [here's the link](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Comment: I've udated my question

Comment: Updated my question again, you see my karma.config.js has the ui-slider in there.

Comment: The only way to really solve this is to see which dependencies you're missing. If you get errors still even when removing the module you need to keep removing the modules you have errors for and find the root dependency that is not being satisfied. You should **not** need to edit the Gruntfile.js the generator should be handling it for you.

Comment: I'm gonna try that tomorrow, hope to make it work. Tried that earlier, removing about 60%, then thought this is taking to long, I need to move on and resolve this later.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I removed the modules giving the error, grunting, checking which module is next, removing that one and so after about 80% of the modules I found the problem in LocalStorageModule. Replacing that one was the hardest, because it's used almost everywhere, but it worked :)

Comment: Those dependencies will get ya! Glad to help! Could you mark this as the answer since you used this method to fix it? Also, I recommend trying ngStorage for accessing the localStorage [Here's the link](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Answer (score 1):

After working for about 4 hours, I finally found the problem! I'm using [LocalStorageModule](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) which normally should work but after grunting it fails. Maybe a wrong configuration, but I replaced it with $cookies and now the website works without errors.

The main reason I used [LocalStorageModule](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) is because it's very easy to autosave filter variables using `localStorageService.bind($scope, 'filters', {}, 'filters');` so they won't be lost when refreshing the page or navigating to detail pages and back.

I'm gonna open an issue on their GitHub and try to find the right configuration to make it work again. Thanks for the help!